# No internet connection during install - Manually run updates (12.04)

Tags: installation

I didn't have access to an internet connection until a few days after my initial ubuntu install.

How do I manually run any updates/scripts that would have run during the normal internet-connected install?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Dash Icon on the upper left of the screen, type up to search, and select Update Manager.  Click on the Check button, then Install updates.  From the command line, just type

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 0):

**Well its simple**

- Open terminal by<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and execute following commadns:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  ```
- That's all you have to do.